# Finding if the next visible node exists

Tags: c#, treeview

I am using treeview in C# and VS2005

```
if ((tempnode1 = tempnode1.NextVisibleNode) != null);
```

I am not able to handle the null reference returned by this statement at the last node of the treeview. Can anyone please suggest a statement to check for null returned by TreeNode.NextVisibleNode

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like ...

```
if( tempnode1 != null && tempnode1.NextVisibleNode != null )
{
  tempnode1 = tempnode1.NextVisibleNode;
}
```

It's a bit more defensive and a bit more readable.

Answer (score 2):

Get rid of the semicolon at the end of the "if" line.

Comment: ... and, in general, don't try to do several things all at once. This kind of code is bad for readability. Put the assignment on a separate line.